# Show additional information in a custom ribbon

Tags: c#, xaml, outlook, outlook-addin, add-in

Today I came across an idea that could come in handy in my daily work. I wanted to create an outlook add-in that shows the user-id (samAccountName) of the sender. I created a new Outlook Add-In and tried my best (I've never created one before).

This is what it looks like at the moment:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
            _explorer = Application.ActiveExplorer();
            _explorer.SelectionChange += _explorer_event;
            _userSearcher = new ActiveDirectoryUserSearcher();
        }

private void _explorer_event() {
            try {
                if (Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0) {
                    var selection = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
                    if (selection is Outlook.MailItem) {
                        var item = selection as Outlook.MailItem;
                        var rec = item.Application.Session.CreateRecipient(item.SenderEmailAddress);
                        var user = rec.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
                        var mail = user.PrimarySmtpAddress;
                        var user2 = _userSearcher.First($"(mail={mail})");

                        //here I'd have to pot some logic to set the text of the control, 
                        //such as "ribbon.EditBox.SetText("blabla");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Now, to show the "content" I'd like to create a new Ribbon element (maybe someone can tell if it's possible to show additional information e.g. below the message body or so?). I've added a new element to my project and called it "DisplayElement".

From different internet sources I tried to figure out how to handly those controls and added the following to the DisplayElement.cs:

```
public string TextBoxText { get; set; }

        public DisplayElement()
        {
        }

        public string onGetText(Office.IRibbonControl control) {
            switch (control.Id.ToLower()) {
                case "user-id-text":
                    return TextBoxText;

            }
            return string.Empty;
        }

        public void onChange(Office.IRibbonControl control, string value) {
            switch (control.Id.ToLower()) {
                case "user-id-text":
                    TextBoxText = value;
                    break;
            }
            return;
        }
```

Unfortunately now I'm totally out. I canÄt figure out how to set the text of the editBox to the senders User-Id.
I'd need something like "_ribbon.EditBox.SetText("blabla");"

DisplayElement XAML:

```
 <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
        <group id="ContentGroup" label="Content">
          <button id="user-id-text" label="Insert Text"
                  screentip="Text" onAction="OnTextButton"
                  supertip="Inserts text at the cursor location."/>
          <editBox id="labelContent" getText="onGetText" onChange="onChange" enabled="false" screentip="User-ID" supertip="Displays the User-ID of the E-Mail Sender."/>

        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get to your ribbon using `Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbonName`.

Be sure, that in your `MyRibbonName.cs` designer's file is

```
partial class ThisRibbonCollection
{
    internal MyRibbonName MyRibbonName
    {
         // Getter
    }
}
```

Then, in your `ThisAddIn` file, you can do following:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private MyRibbonName myRibb;
    private Explorer exp;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myRibb = Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbonName;
        exp = Application.ActiveExplorer();
        exp.SelectionChange += exp_SelectionChange;
    }
}
```

This way you can get to all properties and elements in your `MyRibbonName` Ribbon, including `EditBox` you was looking for in your Q.

*Edit*: I created my ribbon in the following manner:

1. Left mouse click on a project
2. Select Add > New item
3. Select Ribbon (Visual Designer)

In `MyRibbonName.Designer.cs`, `partial class ThisRibbonCollection` is already present.

All you need to do is add visual elements in your ribbon and implement your application's business logic. This is pretty similar to a *Windows Forms* developing.

Comment: Could you, especially the first part of the A, specify what I need to do? How do I get my Class into the Globals.Ribbons Collection?

Comment: @C4p741nZ I Extended my answer